# Sql inner join - разница запроса

Tags: sql

Есть ли разница между

```
select * from a join b
```

и

```
select * from b join a
```

Мне кажется, что разница будет только в outer join, а в inner разницы нет. Это верно?

Comment: sql join diagram - Поиск по картинкам в любом поисковике. Всё будет видно наглядно.

Comment: более того, в данном запросе вы фактически даже не знаете, как по факту оптимизатор решит выполнят запрос. На основе статистик и числа строк первой он возьмет таблицу с меньшим числом строк, даже если это будет таблица `b` а запрос `from a`. В части mysql можно использовать `straight_join` для явного указания порядка соединения, если вы вдруг решили, что умнее оптимизатора.

Answer (score 1):

Если A и B - это таблицы или представления, не использующие переменных, функций и иных хранимых объектов, а сам JOIN - не латеральный, то утверждение скорее всего верно. Иначе скорее всего нет. Впрочем, зависит от диалекта.

**Пример.** B - табличная функция на основе значения выражения, получаемого из таблицы A. Первый запрос легитимен, тогда как второй синтаксически ошибочен. [DEMO в синтаксисе MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/zrMcSte3)

Answer (score 0):

Да, это так.
Пояснение: inner join — это как бы пересечение множеств, т.е. остается только то, что есть в обеих таблицах.